# How to get a youtube.com/user/xxx channel url

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

Just starting playing with YouTube, and trying to get a channel url in the form youtube.com/*user*/{any user name} for a new channel. This is for a third party who want the link in that format.

- I can only seem to generate youtube.com/*channel*/... links
- I do not have 500 subscribers yet so cannot create bespoke url

Have I missed something obvious, or is the .../user/... pattern a leftover from pre Google+ integration?

Looking forward to finding out what I have missed - thanks in advance ;)

Comment: _"Just starting playing with YouTube"_ you mean the **API** or the **website** (new user account, etc)? I want to believe this is a programming question but then you say _"I do not have 500 subscribers yet so cannot create bespoke url"_ as though this is a website user experience issue... Is there a programming language involved in this? Does it allow you to load & process the text of html source code of any given site (no cross-domain issues etc)?

Comment: Good point. This question may not live in SO ... I was asked for a URL to a channel in the /user/... format and could not find a way to create it whether through API or Web front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/user/` URLs are no longer required for channels. This can be further confirmed [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6180214?hl=en). But still, they are supported. You can make you own channel after your username by going to:
[Youtube Account Advanced View](https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced) and clicking on the `Move channel to Brand Account`link.

Comment: This surely works for email-ids created before Google+ era.